# How to solve the Android Runtime: FATAL EXCEPTION and android.view.Inflate Exception?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-emulator, build.gradle, android-manifest

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.blood_bank, PID: 9948
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.blood_bank/com.example.blood_bank.Activities.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.example.blood_bank:layout/activity_login: Binary XML file line #38 in com.example.blood_bank:layout/activity_login: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.example.blood_bank:layout/activity_login: Binary XML file line #38 in com.example.blood_bank:layout/activity_login: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.example.blood_bank:layout/activity_login: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
at com.example.blood_bank.Activities.Login.onCreate(Login.java:33)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:461)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:420)

Comment: please provide the code as well.

Comment: you must provide the code of
1- activity_login
2- Activity Login